# Mocha test won't run on Jenkins and fails with the timeout error

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, timeout, mocha.js

I am not a developer, but a QA person and am new to Node.js. I need help with a mocha test case.

I've a Node.js 8 microservice app with a Mocha 5.0.0 test case that works fine locally but fails with a timeout error on the corporate Jenkins server.

Here's the code:

test.js:

```
var assert = require('assert');
var request = require('request');

describe("My Unit Test",function(done){
    this.timeout(30000);
    // #1 Test to check if the REST app is running
        it("should find the service to be running",function(){
         request('http://my_server:myport', function (error, response, body) {
            assert.equal(response.statusCode, 200, 'REST URL is up'); 
            done();
        });  
...     
        });       
    });
```

Local output:

```
> mocha test.js

  My Unit Test
     √ should find the service to be running (704ms)

  1 passing
```

Jenkins output:

```
[2020-02-21 09:35:28] > mocha test.js --timeout 30000
[2020-02-21 10:22:54]     1) should find the service to be running
[2020-02-21 10:22:54]   0 passing (30s)
[2020-02-21 10:22:54]   1 failing
[2020-02-21 10:22:54]   1) My Unit Test
[2020-02-21 10:22:54]        should find the service to be running:
[2020-02-21 10:22:54]      Error: Timeout of 30000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (/data/cibuild/.../workspace/test.js)
[2020-02-21 10:22:54]   
[2020-02-21 10:23:12] npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
[2020-02-21 10:23:12] Error: Command exited with status 1
```

I've set the timeout from 3000 to 30000, but I always get the Timeout error.

Here's my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node main.js",
    "test": "mocha test.js --timeout 30000"
```

I know request() is obsolete now and got() is preferred, but I can't make too many changes to the test.js file, though I am allowed to tweak it to some extent. Could you please help me with clearing the timeout issue?

Comment: It's likely that in your local environment you can access `my_server:myport`, but Jekins can't. And shouldn't: unit tests are to be isolated from the world. So 1/ this address is actually the codebase being tested, which the developer should test using [supertest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest) or the like, using the _application object_ itself, or 2/ the unit test is trying to handle integration tests and it won't ever work on Jenkins.

Comment: @StockOverflaw based on the opening statement "I am not a developer, but a QA person" I would guess this is not a unit nor integration test, but an API test. So this something Jenkins can be made to automate.

Comment: The Jenkins server is available on the public Internet.

Answer (score 0):

As it was commented by StockOverflaw, Jenkins might not be able to reach your domain. You should get in contact with your DevOps team. I am not too deep in the mess that is micro-service architecture, so I will refrain from making educated guesses on your Test-Environment.

For your issue there are two important questions: 
1. Do you have a properly setup test-environment, which is always up?
2. Does Jenkins have access to it?

Because this timeout indicates that either one is not the case. #1 can cause calls to "get lost", as they are never properly rejected. #2 happens when Jenkins does not have access rights, but the WebServer refuses to reject it. I've met a few enterprises that explained this is a "safety feature", though I never understood it.

Based on your successful local tests I would start with checking #2. For this you have to grab your DevOps team, and ask them to check if Jenkins can access said URL.

Comment: The Jenkins instance is available on a public Internet. Without the `done()` method in `main.js`, the script always passes even if I fail the test with `assert.equal(response.statusCode, 500, 'REST URL is up');`

Comment: done() is just a callback function, which ensures that the test does not finish, before the done() is called. This is required whenever you do anything asynchronous in Mocha (i.e. promises). This has nothing to do with your Jenkins instance. Furthermore, the fact that your Jenkins is public, suggests that it would not have access to your test environment, unless that is public too. Your Jenkins server has to have access to your test environment for your test to work.

Comment: I found that request() is no longer supported and my jenkins server didn't repond to request(). I changed to supertest and now my script works.

Comment: Thanks all for your help.